# identify nature of missingness for categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, data-mining, missing-data, sas

could you please give me some hints for identifying the nature of missingness for categorical variables' missing value? I mean, I gave a fast search on google scholar but I didn't find anything related with this. How could I understand if missing-values are missing completely at random, are they missing at random or finally, they are missing not at random? Except studying the domain I can't think anything. Links to some papers are appreciated, Thanks in advance. (I'll add it in sas environment but the question is not specifically related with this language).

Specifically I'm working on a database related to a disease containing these variables: 1)ID 2)treatment used 3)state of disease when gone to the doctor 4)state of disease after treatment. I'm asking myself if maybe a missing value is related to high values of disease state (patient quite lost, useless to try a treatment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probability of an observation's being missing depends on the value of the observation itself, then it's not "missing at random" and imputation methods aren't appropriate.

In your case, for example, if those with a high state of disease after treatment are more likely to have missing values for the state of disease after treatment, it's not "missing at random." If the missingness of "state after treatment" observations depended on the treatment, however, the data could still be missing at random; the key is the association of an observation's probability of being missing with its own values.

Typically, knowledge of the domain is important for making reasonable assumptions about whether data are "missing at random". I know of no reliable way to determine this from the data themselves.

"Missing completely at random" means no relation between missingness and any of the variables being examined; imputation methods do not require this stringent standard. 
See [this page](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/MI.html) for a good introduction to the issue.

Comment: thank you @EdM for this answer, it gives a fast introduction on the problem. Anyway the domain study gave no idea of the nature of the missing values, but I won't give up with this idea before a partial confirm by data. Actually I'm trying to get some results using frequency values and a chi-squared test.